# send email based on the return of a cell's if statement google sheets

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

My example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/187EJFg1JmhIz-4_yjLuWV3umXINvCI_pQ9lcahyftGc/edit?usp=sharing).

I would like to send an email to recipient1 when any cell in column D is "WINNER".  Also, I would like to send an email to recipient2 when any cell in column E is "WINNER".  My script works when I manually type "WINNER" in any cell in columns D or E.  However, it does not work when a cell changes to "WINNER" as a result of an if statement.  I tried changing the script to true instead of "WINNER", but that also did not work.

```
/**
 * add trigger for onedit -
  * see menu -> Resouces -> Current project's triggers
 */
function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }


  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendNotification")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onEdit()
  .create();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendNotification2")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onEdit()
  .create();

};


/**
 *
 */

function sendNotification(f) {


  if("D" == f.range.getA1Notation().charAt(0)) {

    if(f.value == "WINNER") {

//Define Notification Details
      var recipients = "adam@gmail.com";
      var subject = "Update"+f.range.getSheet().getName();
      var body = "Adam just won the lottery!";

  //Send the Email
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }
  }
}

function sendNotification2(f) {


  if("E" == f.range.getA1Notation().charAt(0)) {

    if(f.value == "WINNER") {



  //Define Notification Details
      var recipients = "geo@gmail.com";
      var subject = "Update"+f.range.getSheet().getName();
      var body = "Geo just won the lottery!";

  //Send the Email
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I remember reading about which things actually trigger on edit, but I can't find the documentation now. Have you tried changing your if logic to directly trigger you sendNotification functions?

Answer (score 0):

You may check with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298160/how-to-trigger-an-email-notification-when-cell-value-is-modified-by-function). You can use a simple script that runs on a timer trigger and checks for any modification in a specific column in your sheet.

Sample code:

```
function checkColumnF() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sh.getRange('F1:F').getValues().join('-');
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){ // first time you run the script
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('oldValues', values);
    return;
  }
  var oldValues = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('oldValues').split('-');
  var valuesArray = values.split('-');
  while (valuesArray.length>oldValues.length){
    oldValues.push('x'); // if you append some rows since last exec
  }
  Logger.log('oldValues = '+oldValues)
  Logger.log('current values = '+valuesArray)
  for(var n=0;n<valuesArray.length;n++){
    if(oldValues[n] != valuesArray[n]){ // check for any difference
      sendMail(n+1,valuesArray[n]);
    }
  }  
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('oldValues', values);
}

function sendMail(row,val){
  Logger.log('value changed on row '+row+' value = '+val+' ,  mail sent');
  // uncomment below when you are sure everything runs fine to avoid sending dozens of emails while you test !
  //MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),'value changed in your sheet','Row '+row+' is now '+val);
}
```

Additional reference: [Email notifications with body/subject containing cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173154/email-notifications-with-body-subject-containing-cell-value)